# jQuery Ajax $.parseJSON works on Localhost but not on server

Tags: jquery, ajax, parse-javascript-sdk

Hello everybody and thank you in advance for your help.

I have a infinite scroll script that I have develop and working on localhost but not on my server.

The JS code look like this :

```js
$('#load-more').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
}).on('click', function slide(event) {
  var relData = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('rel'));

  $('#loader').html('<img src="design/loader.gif" alt="" />');

  var data = {
    displayedSites: relData.displayedSites,
    catNum: relData.catNum,
    streamPage: relData.streamPage,
    numSites: relData.numSites
  };

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/infinite-scroll.php',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 3000,
    success: function(data) {
      $('#sitesstream').fadeOut(100, function() {
        $(this).append(data.newSitesSet);
      }).fadeIn(1000);
      $('#loader').html('');
      if (data.moreSitesRel.active != 'off') {
        $('#load-more').show();
        $('#load-more').attr('rel', '{"displayedSites":"' + data.moreSitesRel.displayedSites + '", "catNum":"' + data.moreSitesRel.catNum + '", "streamPage":"' + data.moreSitesRel.streamPage + '", "numSites":"' + data.moreSitesRel.numSites + '"}');
      } else {
        $('#load-more').hide();
      }
    },
    error: function() {
      $('#siteStreamInfo').text('Problem');
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

It calls a PHP file to add more content and send back to the page.

Do you have an idea of what is missing or what I should add / change to make it works on my server, which is a >7 php version.
I also use jQuery version 3.5.1

Thank you so much.

Comment: How does it _"not work"_? Do you have any errors reported in your dev-tools console? What does your `#load-more` element look like, especially its `rel` attribute?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you Phil for your help.
I have removed the cursor thing and put it in my CSS :)

I finaly soldev my problem which wasn't a jQuery JSON problem but a PDO query on the infinite-scroll.php file.

Which is weird.

Query was:

```
$sitesQuery = 'SELECT '.$fields.' FROM annuaire_sites AS sites LEFT JOIN countries AS coun ON coun.id = sites.loc_country WHERE sites.category = '.$page['catNum'].' and sites.valid = 1 and sites.premium = 0 ORDER BY sites.date_ins DESC, sites.hour_ins DESC LIMIT :start, :perpage';

        $res_sites = $bdd->prepare($sitesQuery);
    
        $res_sites->bindValue(':start', 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $res_sites->bindValue(':perpage', 60, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $res_sites->execute();
        $res_sites->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I replaced by:

```
$sitesQuery = 'SELECT '.$fields.' FROM annuaire_sites AS sites LEFT JOIN countries AS coun ON coun.id = sites.loc_country WHERE sites.category = '.$catNum.' and sites.valid = 1 and sites.premium = 0 ORDER BY sites.date_ins DESC, sites.hour_ins DESC LIMIT '.$start.', '.$displayedSites.'';

$res_sites = $bdd->prepare($sitesQuery);

$res_sites->execute();
$res_sites->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I adandonned the bindValue thing which was the source of the problem for a reason I don't know! Because I use this same query on some pages and it works fine...

If someone has an explaination...

Anyway, thank you for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

As a basic rule-of-thumb, **NEVER** manually craft your own JSON strings.

You're probably running into something in the returned data that makes your JSON invalid when you set it back into the `rel` attribute.

Instead, use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```js
$("#load-more").attr("rel", JSON.stringify({
  displayedSites: data.moreSitesRel.displayedSites,
  catNum: data.moreSitesRel.catNum,
  streamPage: data.moreSitesRel.streamPage,
  numSites: data.moreSitesRel.numSites
}));
```

---

FYI, your `mouseenter` handler would be much simpler as actual CSS

```css
#load-more { cursor: pointer; }
```

You don't even need a `:hover` since `cursor` rules only apply on mouse-over.